# jquery ajax form validation not working in chrome

Tags: ajax, forms, validation, google-chrome

I have the simple task of validating a user has entered the first name.  This is working in most browsers but chrome doesn't seem to be getting a response from ajaxfirstname.php.  Here is the script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
var validatefirst_name = jQuery('#validatefirst_name');
jQuery('#first_name').keyup(function () {
var t = this; 
if (this.value != this.lastValue) {
  if (this.timer) clearTimeout(this.timer);
  validatefirst_name.removeClass('error').html('<span style="margin-left: 5px;"><img src="images/loader.gif" height="16" width="16" /></span>');

  this.timer = setTimeout(function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "ajaxfirstname.php",
      data: "action=check_first_name&first_name=" + t.value,
      dataType: "json",
      async: false,
      type: "post",
      success: function (j) {
        validatefirst_name.html(j.msg);
      }
    });
  }, 200);

  this.lastValue = this.value;
}
});
});
```

and my html

```
<label for="first_name">First Name</label>
<input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name" value="<?php 
$name = explode(' ',$this->my->name);
echo $name[0];
?>">
<span id="validatefirst_name"></span>
```

I opened up the developer tool but I don't see any error on this particular script.  Does anyone have suggestions on this?  Does the above code look correct?  Would Chrome have any issues with it?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

May be its because you have used id in textbox twice ["id="first_name"].Please change this and let me know..

id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" **id="first_name"** value="my->name);